# How to install SSH2 module to LAMPP?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, xampp

I am trying to install an SSH2 module to LAMPP but it does not want to start with it.

I downloaded all the necessary files, and when I add the `extension=libssh2.so` to the `opt/lampp/etc/php.ini` and restart LAMPP, PHP does not load up and when I enter my web address, then it goes straight to download and does not show.

OS: Linux Mint 14 Nadia 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the difficulties with installing libssh2 that I prefer [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). Good luck!